# ImportExcel PowerShell Module : how to Change color of next colum in excel using powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am reading a json file and exporting excel of the column I want. I am able to find the value of an array and highlight that value in component tab of excel, but I want to highlight column no. A, B and F. here is my script:

```
    $Modules | Select-Object filename,pathname,productVersion |Sort-Object -Property filename | Export-Excel  -Path $FilePath -WorksheetName "HighlightedComponents" -BoldTopRow -AutoSize
    $json.Products.info |Sort-Object -Property filename  | Export-Excel -Path $FilePath -WorksheetName "Components" -Append -AutoSize


    $ExcelPkg = Open-ExcelPackage -Path  $FilePath

    $Worksheet = $ExcelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets["Components"].Cells
    ForEach($module in $Modules){
    ForEach($value in $Worksheet){
        If($value.value -contains $module.filename){
            Write-Host $value -ForegroundColor Cyan
            $Colum = $value.Columns
            Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $ExcelPkg.Components -Address $value.address -RuleType ContainsText -BackgroundColor Yellow
            #Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $ExcelPkg.Components -Address $Colum + 2  -RuleType ContainsText -BackgroundColor Yellow
        }
    }

    }
   Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $ExcelPkg -Show
```

Comment: This is also a good place for `ImportExcel` issues. https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues

Comment: As an aside: since `$value` is a single cell, `$value.value -contains $module.filename` is effectively the same as `$value.value -eq $module.filename`. `

Answer (score 1):

See: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

`Add-ConditionalFormatting` which you are already using but need to make some adjustments.

Here's a modification to your script:

```
$Modules | Select-Object filename, pathname, productVersion | Sort-Object -Property filename | Export-Excel -Path $FilePath -WorksheetName "HighlightedComponents" -BoldTopRow -AutoSize

$json.Products.info | Sort-Object -Property filename | Export-Excel -Path $FilePath -WorksheetName "Components" -Append -AutoSize

$ExcelPkg = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $FilePath
$Worksheet = $ExcelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets["Components"]

Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $Worksheet -Address "A:A" -RuleType ContainsText -BackgroundColor Yellow
Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $Worksheet -Address "B:B" -RuleType ContainsText -BackgroundColor Yellow
Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $Worksheet -Address "F:F" -RuleType ContainsText -BackgroundColor Yellow

ForEach ($module in $Modules) {
   ForEach ($value in $Worksheet.Cells) {
       If ($value.Value -contains $module.filename) {
           Write-Host $value -ForegroundColor Cyan
           $Column = $value.Column
           Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $Worksheet -Address $Column -RuleType ContainsText -BackgroundColor Yellow
       }
   }
}

Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $ExcelPkg -Show
```

This will highlight columns A, B, and F with yellow background color. Please test and let me know if this helps.